# Word meaning "to walk/run around something"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> I [...] the house to see what was happening in the yard.

I thought of *encircle* and *surround*. But I'm not sure if can use them to mean "to walk around something."

Comment: I'd just use "went round".

Comment: @Mari-Lou A OK, edited the post. How about now?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It's less open to ambiguity.

Comment: Do you mean all the way around or just part of the way around?  "to see what was happening in the yard" implies only partially, which really rules out **circle** or **circumnavigate**

Comment: @itsbruce - circumnavigate does not necessarily mean to go all around something in a full circle, it can also mean to bypass/avoid something http://www.thefreedictionary.com/circumnavigate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **cross** and **traverse** will fit in almost all contexts.

And if it is some close space **pass/go/cross through** might work as well.

Comment: You are answering the question title, but the OP is looking for an expression which means to "**walk round** something".

Comment: I agree that my answer was influenced by the title, but the body didn't clearly state that only going round should be considered.

Comment: It's not your fault, but sometimes it's best to ask clarification from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has already mentioned circumnavigate. However, according to Merriam Webster Dictionary, circumnavigate means "to travel all the way around (something) in a ship, airplane, etc.".

I believe the word you are looking for is **circumambulate**, which means "to circle on foot especially ritualistically".

I circumambulated the house to see what was happening in the yard.

Additionally, you may also use **circled**, which means "to move in a circle or circuit around; rotate or revolve around", as opposed to encircled, which means "to form a circle around; surround; encompass" or "to make a circling movement around; make the circuit of"

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of **circumnavigate**. I admit is does sound unusual to say "I *circumnavigated* the house to get the yard", however, if it's a single word you are looking for, the second part of the definition below does seem to fit.

From [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumnavigate)

> circumnavigate - to go completely around (as the earth) especially by water; also :  to go around instead of through :  bypass

Comment: I circumnavigate the house..sounds bit queer.. does it?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned in my answer that it sounds unusual. However, it is a single-word answer that means to go around something

Comment: What kind of house design would force somebody to go **completely** around a house to see the yard?  Is it built on a Mobius strip?

Comment: The second part of the definition is that it can mean to go around something, to bypass/avoid it, not necessarily *entirely* around it. For example, from TFD - 'circumnavigate the downtown traffic'. I don't think that means you would need to drive in a full circle around the traffic in order to avoid it, which as you point out makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

I ***rounded*** the house to see what was happening in the yard.

http://www.yourdictionary.com/rounded#websters

Answer (score 0):

Skirted: go around or past the edge of.

"he did not go through the city but skirted it"

synonyms:   go around, walk around, circle
"he skirted the city"